# How to automatically include `.withGraphFetched()` for all queries of model in objection.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I have the following model defined:

```js
import db from "../connection.js";
import objection from "objection";
const { Model } = objection;

Model.knex(db);

class User extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return "users";
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      emails: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: Email,
        join: {
          from: "users.id",
          to: "emails.user_id",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class Email extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return "emails";
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      user: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: User,
        join: {
          from: "emails.user_id",
          to: "users.id",
        },
      },
    };
  }
}
```

And to query a `User` with their email addresses would require `withGraphFetched()` to be explicitly run every time as:

```js
const myUser = await User.query().withGraphFetched("emails").findById(1)
```

I haven't been able to figure out what to write in the Model definition to make this possible, and I don't see any such examples online. Is it possible to ALWAYS have `withGraphFetched("emails")` automatically included in the query so it doesn't have to be explicitly written out every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such thing doesnt exist. Maybe you could create the logic in the [`beforeFind`](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/static-methods.html#static-beforefind) hook adding the eager loader to the knex instance, but it could generate a lot of undesired and strange side-effects.

The normal practice is adding a method to that specific case:

```
class User extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return "users";
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      emails: {
        relation: Model.HasManyRelation,
        modelClass: Email,
        join: {
          from: "users.id",
          to: "emails.user_id",
        }
      }
    }
  }

  static async getUser (id) { // Or maybe getUserWithEmails
      return await this.query().withGraphFetched("emails").findById(id)
  }
}
```

Then you can just:

```
const myUser = await User.getUser(id)
```